# NSData dataWithContentsOfFile 100% leak in instruments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios6

**UPDATED** 
Why `NSData dataWithContentsOfFile` line is showing leak in Instruments?
I am using ARC. Deployment Target is iOS 5.0

```
@autoreleasepool
{
    AudioPlayerAV *context = [userInfo valueForKey:@"self"];
    NSString *filepath = [userInfo valueForKey:@"filepath"];
    [context.player stop];

    //check if file is there fetch player from dict
    AVAudioPlayer *_player = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *filedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath];

    _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithData:filedata error:&error]; 
    context.player = _player;
    NSLog(@"loadAndPlay error : %@",[error description]);
    context.player.numberOfLoops = (context.loop)?-1:0;
    context.player.volume = context.volume;
    [context.player play];
}
```

Comment: 100% allocation or 100% leak? Doesn't it mean that increase in allocations at this point is 100% caused by this object?

Comment: and `dataWithContentsOfFile` returns an `autoreleased` object. It shouldn't be a leak

Comment: @Atif of course it doesn't but that is creating a leak but live bytes are increasing with each leak.

Comment: If this code is in a cycle, I suggest you put the body of the cycle into an autorelease block. That way it should not increase.

Comment: thanks @Levi, but this line is already in autoreleasepool block..

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, instruments points to the wrong line, I think it is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498015/leak-from-nsurl-and-avaudioplayer-using-arc) leak in [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).

from: [Leak from NSURL and AVAudioPlayer using ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498015/leak-from-nsurl-and-avaudioplayer-using-arc)

> Looks to be a leak in Apple's code... I tried using both
>
> -[AVAudioPlayer initWithData:error:] and
> -[AVAudioPlayer initWithContentsOfURL:error:]
>
> In the first case, the allocated AVAudioPlayer instance retains the passed in NSData. In the second, the passed in NSURL is retained.
>
> You can see the AVAudioPlayer object then creates a C++ object AVAudioPlayerCpp, which retains the NSData again
>
> Later, when the AVAudioPlayer object is released, the NSData is released, but there's never a release call from the associated AVAudioPlayerCpp... (You can tell from the attached image)

Check it out, there are some instruments screenshots attached in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12659674/672989).