# How to solve leak in this Code (ARC enabled)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, ios6, avaudioplayer

Here is my Code(ARC enabled) where memory leak is seen.

Please help me to solve this issue.

```
- (void) setMusic
{      
     /*
     Initialise and set the music for the game.
     */

 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"actionMusic" ofType:@"caf"]];
NSError *error = nil;
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
if (!error)
{
    _audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    if(_musicFlag)
    {
        [_audioPlayer play];
    }
    [_audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:INT32_MAX];
}

error = nil;
url =nil;

url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pew" ofType:@"wav"]];
_moveMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

if (!error)
{
    _audioPlayer.delegate = self;
}

error = nil;
url =nil;


url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Won" ofType:@"wav"]];
_winningMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

if (!error)
{
    _winningMusic.delegate = self;
    [_winningMusic setNumberOfLoops:1];
}

}
```

[image: Here is the detals of the leak]
[image]

Comment: ARC is enabled .........

Comment: Comment out things until the memory leak stops. The last line that the memory leak occured on is the cause.

Comment: What is telling you there's a leak?  What line is reported as causing the leak.  How are your properties declared?

Comment: Can you share details like what the static analyzer found, what you found in Instruments?

Comment: Side note: All of your `if` statements are incorrect. You should only check `error` if the return value of the methods is `nil`. So the first should be: `if (_audioPlayer)`.

Comment: @HotLicks  i have put put stack trace . Please help

Comment: @rmaddy So memory leak might be due to if condition?

Comment: @CarlVeazey I have put up the details of instruments!

Comment: @Vinu1991 Not at all. I was pointing out an unrelated problem with your code.

Comment: @rmaddy so what in this code is leading to memory leak? any idea?

Comment: The posted code looks fine. You need to provide better details from Instruments. The screen shot you posted is not helpful. Also, run the analyzer in Xcode.

Comment: @rmaddy added one more image that wud be hepful to solve the issue

Comment: @Vinu1991 No, that's not helpful either. You need to show the screen where Instruments shows you the line that causes the leak and the line where the memory was allocated.

Comment: @rmaddy how to get those line numnbers?

Comment: @Vinu1991 Sorry, those come from the analyzer in Xcode, not Instruments. Go to the Project menu and select Analyze.

Comment: @rmaddy static analyser is already set in the project.. it does not show any error nor any warnings!

Comment: @rmaddy Leak is due to AVAudioPlayer foundation class i.e in the apple code . Thanks alot for putting in efforts to solve my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for the leak.

This leak is due to `AVAudioPlayer` foundation class which is yet to be fixed by Apple.

Thus Usage of `AVAudioPlayer` foundation class leads to leaks.

[Check This link for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498015/leak-from-nsurl-and-avaudioplayer-using-arc)