# AVAudioPlayer leaks memory after using ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6

In my Project I have a table View.. which has having accessory buttons.

So when I click on button the sound will play...
if the sound is already playing then it will stop...

here is my code....

```
-(void)playAudio:(int)index
{

    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",soundListArray[index]]                                                             ofType:@"mp3"];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath] error:nil];

    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [audioPlayer play];

}
```

I am also stopping it when player has finished.

I already searched a lot...
i also applied this after every stop but it won't affect....

```
audioPlayer = nil;
audioPlayer.delegate = nil;
```

Comment: Here is your answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498015/leak-from-nsurl-and-avaudioplayer-using-arc

Comment: why do you say it leaks? Have you profiled that?

Comment: Looks to be a leak in Apple's code... THIS IS THE ANSWER @Rixian..

Comment: Yes i have profiled that.... @GabrielePetronella

Comment: The order of `audioPlayer = nil; audioPlayer.delegate = nil;` is important!

Comment: which should be nil first @ tojanfoe...

Comment: @trojanfoe... i had use both but still there is problem