# AVAudioPlayer preloaded sound leaks from memory

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, background, avaudioplayer

I have an AVAudioPlayer instance that loads sound in memory with `audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()`, and then after a few start playing it. I have a problem that in approximately ten minutes after entering background, it leaks from memory and I is not being prepared. After that fed hours, I don't have an ability to run `prepareToPlay()` again. How to leave that preloaded sound in memory for a long term? I am preparing sound to play in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`method:

```
let dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
    dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, {[weak self] in
        var audioSessionError: NSError?

        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self!, selector: "handleInterruption:", name: AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification, object: nil)
        audioSession.setActive(true, error: nil)

        if (audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: &audioSessionError)) {
            println("Successfully set the audio session")
        } else {
            println("Could not set the audio session")
        }

        let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sound", ofType:"mp3")
        let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
        var error:NSError?

        self!.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data: fileData, error: &error)

        self!.audioPlayer?.numberOfLoops = -1

        self!.audioPlayer?.delegate = self

        if (self?.audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay() != false) {
            println("Successfully prepared for playing")
        } else {
            println("Failed to prepare for playing")
        }
    })
```

Then in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` I am trying to play it in background: `self.audioPlayer?.play()`, it **returns `true`**. Probably it works, but after about 10 - 20 minutes it does not work. And note that `.play()` now **returns `false`**.

1. *Is there a sense to disable ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) to release and dealloc `audioPlayer` manually?*
2. *Maybe I need to use lower level APIs such as `OpenAL`? However I won't use it since it is deprecated in iOS 9 and later I will need to rewrite it without `OpenAL`.*
3. *Any more ideas? Maybe I need to use `Audio Units` with `RemoteIO`? If it will work, provide some examples please.*
4. *Maybe there are third party frameworks like [`ObjectAL`](https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone) - an easy implementation of `OpenAL`. As I know it is available in iOS 9.*

These methods are just my assumptions. But them main question remains the same: **Will those methods work from background?**

Comment: tried this link ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498015/leak-from-nsurl-and-avaudioplayer-using-arc

Comment: It does not look like an answer

Comment: Disable ARC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project

Comment: have you tried doing this and do you have an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just disable ARC. When you enter backgroud, then if you don't use it it is being released. In Swift create AVAudioPlayer as `Unmanaged<T>` object.