# Swift: Unmanaged AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting

I have `AVAudioPlayer` instance:

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
self!.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data: fileData, error: &error)
self!.audioPlayer?.numberOfLoops = -1
self!.audioPlayer?.delegate = self

if (self?.audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay() != false) {
    println("Successfully prepared for playing")
} else {
    println("Failed to prepare for playing")
}
```

I need to disable ARC for this `AVAudioPlayer`. `Unmanaged`  is not well-documentated, so it is pretty hard to do that. Here's what I've tried:

```
var audioPlayer: Unmanaged<AVAudioPlayer>!
//Stuck after creating nil instance, what to do now?
self!.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data: fileData, error: &error)
self!.audioPlayer?.numberOfLoops = -1
self!.audioPlayer?.delegate = self

if (self?.audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay() != false) {
    println("Successfully prepared for playing")
} else {
    println("Failed to prepare for playing")
}
```

Comment: "creating nil instance" - `var audioPlayer: Unmanaged<AVAudioPlayer>!` - empty AVAudioPlayer

Comment: It would be interesting to know *why* you want to "disable ARC". Could this be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/196432) ?

Comment: `var audioPlayer: Unmanaged<AVAudioPlayer>!` declares a variable, it does not create anything.

Comment: Here's original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212670/avaudioplayer-preloaded-sound-leaks-from-memory

Comment: That's why I need to disable ARC

Comment: That's not your real code. Please show real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write:

```
// Properties in your class
var unmanagedAudioPlayer: Unmanaged<AVAudioPlayer>
var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!

// code
self.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(...)
self.unmanagedAudioPlayer = Unmanaged.passRetained(self.audioPlayer)
```

Now you can use `self.audioPlayer` as usual as an `AVAudioPlayer` (or `AVAudioPlayer!` if you prefer, but I don't see why).

`self.unmanagedAudioPlayer` keeps a retained reference of `self.audioPlayer` such that it cannot be deallocated by ARC.

When you are done with this `AVAudioPlayer` object, you can call `self.unmanagedAudioPlayer.release()` (or `autorelease`) to release it as if you are doing the same in Objective-C.

In fact you don't need to store `self.audioPlayer` separately, because you can always get it via `unmanagedAudioPlayer.takeUnratainedValue()` but it is a nice alias to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

This is an un-question. The suggestion to "turn off ARC" is wrong, and you should not be trying to do it. If you have a memory issue you should be tackling it directly. For example, if there's a problem with an AVAudioPlayer in the background, set it to `nil` as you enter the background, to release it from memory. But even more important, you should be asking yourself why you have this problem to start with. I've been using AVAudioPlayer for years and I've never had a situation where "it leaks from memory" (whatever you mean by that).